# Como envio o valor escolhido dentro de um option que tem uma consulta no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php session_start();
include 'conexao.php';
?>
<form action="recebe.php" method="POST">
  <select class="browser-default custom-select">
  <option name="arrays"value="nenhum">Nenhum</option>
    <option name="arrays"value="<?php ['id_cane']?>"><?php                                
      sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM CNAE ") 
        or die(mysqli_error($conn));
   while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
     ?><option ><?php
    echo "".$aux["descricao"]."<br/>"; //outro atributo de toda pesquisa feito pelo $sql
 } ?>
      </option> </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>

</form>

recebe  o valor na pagina recebe.php
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'conexao.php';  
    $arrays = $_POST["arrays"];   

    echo "<script>
    alert ($arrays)           
  </script>";

?>
```

Comment: Coloque uma explicação de seus problemas e de como seu código funciona. Se você não tiver capricho com a sua pergunta não serão os outros que o terão com a sua resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi do seu código, você quer montar uma lista de options com base no conteúdo de uma tabela chamada CNAE. Se esta tabela tiver os campos de "id_cnae" e "descricao", o código para montar o formulário e receber o valor na página recebe.php ficaria da seguinte forma:

```html
<?
php session_start();
include 'conexao.php';
?>

<form action="recebe.php" method="POST">
 
 <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="arrays">
  
 <option value="nenhum">Nenhum</option>
    
 <?php                                
    sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM CNAE") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
    ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $aux->id_cnae;?>"><?php echo $aux->descricao;?></option> 
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>


<?php
 //recebe  o valor na pagina recebe.php
    session_start();
    include 'conexao.php';  
 if (isset($_POST["arrays"])){
    $arrays = $_POST["arrays"];   
  print_r( $arrays);
 }
?>
```

Comment: me ajudou, só que não está mostrando resultado da pesquisa no option, fica a quantidade mas não chega a mostrar; ficou assim : <div class="form-group" >  <label for="inputCNAE">Atividade Primária</label>
<br/>                                   
<select class="browser-default custom-select">
<?php                                
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id_cnae, descricao FROM CNAE") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
?>
<option value="<?php print $aux->id_cnae;?>"><?php print $aux->descricao;?></option> 
<?php }
?>
 </select>
</div>